# Why does my question have so few views? And how can I increase them?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, views

Yesterday, I bountied [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501219/how-to-send-keys-to-a-canvas-element-for-longer-duration) I had asked 27 days ago (my first bounty). And I am surprised at the lack of views on it. Before applying the bounty, the question had ~40 views, I believe. Now it has 45. I have also not received any comments/upvotes/downvotes...

Is there a particular reason for such a lack of views and interest in my question? And more importantly, how can I increase them?

- I had edited the question prior to setting a bounty. Was this edit too cosmetic and unnecessarily distracting (lots of `code blocks`, **bold** and *italics*)?
- Is `Selenium` inherently less likely to be viewed/answered?
- Is my question clearly explained? The minimal, complete, and verifiable example I had provided seems to have confused the only answerer on the question... Should I add more code to it?
- Can you suggest a better title for my question?

Usually, my questions are bombarded with downvotes/comments. The complete lack of them seems unsettling.

Comment: Seems you just created the bounty 10 hours ago? Give it more time... also, today is weekend, so the activity is relatively slower than usual.

Comment: 1 year later, it's nice to see you got around 700 views and 5 answers :)